# Auth0 and Angular: Syncing User fields

Tags: angularjs, auth0

I would like to use Auth0 in my Angular web project. Several sites need information from more than one user (e.g., user_id, picture, and name).

Since I want to avoid making Auth0 API calls for each user, I came with the idea up to sync the user fields with my SQL database.

How can I handle this?

My first idea was to create a user in my SQL databas when they successfully signed up using Auth0. How can I catch this event?

Really appreciate any help.

Thanks.